# How to upload a file from input type file in dart?

Tags: file-upload, dart

After searching a lot I am unable to deserialise a simple text file while uploading through dart.

I know this may trigger lot of down votes but a simple demo of how to upload files in dart would be helpful ?

both in console as well in web app in dart.I just  want to upload a text file with some basic words in it nothing else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following simple example works for me:

With the following file structure in the editor:

```
fileuploadtest/
  fileupload.dart
  index.html
```

**index.html** (note: no Dart here!)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>index</title>
  </head>

  <body>   
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="foo" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
        Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>   
  </body>
</html>
```

**fileupload.dart**

This creates a static file handler that (for simplicity) always serves `index.html` in response to any `GET` request , and a File Upload Handler that responds to any POST request and prints out the content of an uploaded file (well, actually, the entire POST data - you'll have to extract the relevant bit).

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  var httpServer = new HttpServer();

  // attach handlers:

  var static = new StaticFileHandler();
  httpServer.addRequestHandler(static.matcher, static.handler);

  var fileUploadHandler = new FileUploadHandler();
  httpServer.addRequestHandler(fileUploadHandler.matcher, 
      fileUploadHandler.handler);

  // start listening
  httpServer.listen("127.0.0.1", 8081);
}

class FileUploadHandler {
  bool matcher(req) => req.method == "POST"; // return true if method is POST

  void handler(req,res) {
    req.inputStream.onData = () {
      var data = req.inputStream.read();
      var content = new String.fromCharCodes(data);
      print(content); // print the file content.
    };
  }
}

class StaticFileHandler {
  //  return true for all GET requests.
  bool matcher(req) {
    print("Path: ${req.path}");
    return req.method=="GET"; 
  }

  void handler(req,res) {
    var file = new File("index.html"); // only serve index.html in the same folder
    file.openInputStream().pipe(res.outputStream);
  }
}
```

Start `fileUpload.dart` and use an browser to navigate to `http://localhost:8081/index.html`

For a file called `foo.txt`, containing the following content:

```
foo
bar
```

This is the entire log output I get (posted from the the Dart Editor's console)

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryw7XBqLKuA7nP1sKc

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"

100000

------WebKitFormBoundaryw7XBqLKuA7nP1sKc

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedfile"; filename="foo.txt"

Content-Type: text/plain

foo
bar

------WebKitFormBoundaryw7XBqLKuA7nP1sKc--
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I still wonder if we should AJAX/WS upload files nowadays instead of the old form stuff ;) ... you know, to be able to cancel an ongoing upload, see the progress, etc.

Comment: Fair point. I was trying to find the simplest answer for the server side.

Comment: It indeed is. I've been wanting to write a file upload package for a while, but haven't yet found the time. Let's see if this weekend is different.